# How to encode IImageProvider as a PNG image?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, png, windows-8.1, win-universal-app, lumia-imaging-sdk

Assuming I have a LumiaImagingSDK rendering chain setup, with a final IImageProvider object that I want to render, how do I encode that into a PNG image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lumia Imaging SDK supports PNG images as input, however there isn't a "PNG Renderer" avaliable in the SDK.

Luckily if you are developing for Windows 8.1 (StoreApplication / universal application / Windows phone 8.1 project) there is a Windows encoder (Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder) you can use.

Assuming the IImageProvider you want to render is called "source" this is a code snippet you can use to encode the resulting image as PNG:

```
using Lumia.Imaging;
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
using System.IO;

...

using (var renderer = new BitmapRenderer(source, ColorMode.Bgra8888))
{
    var bitmap = await renderer.RenderAsync();
    byte[] pixelBuffer = bitmap.Buffers[0].Buffer.ToArray();


    using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, (uint)bitmap.Dimensions.Width, (uint)bitmap.Dimensions.Height, 96, 96, pixelBuffer);
        await encoder.FlushAsync().AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);

       //If InMemoryRandomAccessStream (IRandomAccessStream) works for you, end here.
       //If you need an IBuffer, here is how you get one:

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            memoryStream.Capacity = (int)stream.Size;
            var ibuffer = memoryStream.GetWindowsRuntimeBuffer();
            await stream.ReadAsync(ibuffer, (uint)stream.Size, InputStreamOptions.None).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you bytes in memory as either `InMemoryRandomAccessStream` (`IRandomAccessStream`) or an `IBuffer` depending on what you need. You can then save the buffer to disk or pass it to other parts of your application.